# Is there a way to have components in CQ 5.6 inherit editConfig properties?

Tags: aem

I'm trying to figure out how to set `cq:disableTargeting=true` for all components that can be added to the parsys. I tried setting the `cq:childEditConfig` in the parsys `cq:editConfig` however this approach did not work. I believe this is because each component has it's own `cq:editConfig`. Is there another way to set a property that child components can inherit within their own `cq:editConfig`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your components are inheriting (`sling:resourceSuperType`) from foundation/components/parbase for example, than probably you can make an [overlay](https://docs.adobe.com/docs/en/aem/6-0/develop/platform/overlays.html) of that component by defining `cq:editConfig` with the new settings. But you still have a problem if one of the components you have overwrite the `cq:editConfig` with other settings.

Comment: All of our custom components implement their own cq:editConfig. So I'm guessing there isn't a way to have each custom component inherit a property. I'm trying to disable the "target" functionality introduced in 5.6. We do not use targeting and would like to disable it to avoid confusion and problems for authors.